# wcstombs_s(), length of converted string

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

```
errno_t wcstombs_s(
   size_t *pReturnValue,
   char *mbstr,
   size_t sizeInBytes,
   const wchar_t *wcstr,
   size_t count
);
```

[Microsoft VS2019's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcstombs-s-wcstombs-s-l?view=vs-2019) says:

> *pReturnValue*
>   The size in bytes of the converted string, **including** the null terminator.
>
> ...
>
> If `wcstombs_s` successfully converts the source string, it puts the size in bytes of the converted string, **including** the null terminator, into `*pReturnValue` (provided `pReturnValue` is not NULL).

[cppreference.com's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wcstombs) says:

> **retval**    -   pointer to a size_t object where the result will be stored
>
> ...
>
> Returns zero on success (in which case the number of bytes **excluding** terminating zero that were, or would be written to `dst`, is stored in `*retval`)

Who is wrong ?

Comment: Probably both of them. Microsoft will still be using their `_s`  functions that precede the `_s` functions now in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. The cppreference is referring to the standards compliant version of the function. The Microsoft documentation is referring to the version implemented in their standard library.

If you're using MS Visual C++, use the Microsoft docs. Otherwise, use the cppreference docs.

Comment: Microsoft is well-known for not following standards.

Comment: Microsoft rammed this particular (thankfully optional) standard, Annex K, through the process specifically to derail the standard language by having it specify something contrary to the only existing implementation of these interfaces. Fortunately, they're useless and nobody else is interested in implementing them. Ignore all the `_s` functions and just pretend they don't exist. They do not solve any real problem.